# Delete by Query API throws type [[_delete_by_query, trying to auto create mapping, but dynamic mapping is disabled]] missing]

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elastic Search version `number: "1.7.1"`
But whenever I run the `_delete_by_query` I get this error on all my indexes.
Here's the mapping for one of the indexes

```
{
  "composite_task_group": {
    "mappings": {
      "stock_take": {
        "dynamic": "true",
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "strings": {
              "mapping": {
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "type": "string"
              },
              "match_mapping_type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "data": {
            "properties": {
              "attributes.container_id": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "attributes.container_label": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "attributes.container_type": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "attributes.ref_id": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "attributes.stock_take_id": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "attributes.stock_take_type": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "attributes.wid": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "client_id": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "createdAtEpoch": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "facility_id": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "resources.id": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "resources.type": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "status": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "tenant_id": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "updatedAtEpoch": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "tenant": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the `_delete_by_query` that I am using to delete all documents that have the value of "A" for `facility_id`

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "A",
      "default_field": "facility_id"
    }
  }
}
```

The same payload returns 600 documents for `_search` API

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `_delete_by_query` [wasn't available](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query) in ver 1.7.

The correct way to delete by query would in your case be

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://xyz:9200/index_name/composite_task_group/_query' -d '{
    "query" : {
       ...
    }
}
'
```

The error you're seeing is typically thrown when you're **inserting** a new document to an index that [required types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html), thus trying to update its mapping but that mapping is optionally prohibited from being dynamically updated, hence the statement "dynamic mapping is disabled".

Comment: Thanks a ton, I was probably lost in the documentation :)

Comment: I can imagine :) You can select the ES version in the docs btw: https://prnt.sc/vzlqpm